# how to read from file and add to object data?

Tags: java

```
17  5
12  8
15  22
17  11
33  21
43  15
15  4
44  35
23  19
10  23
55  39
8   6
21  9
20  28
20  13
45  29
18  16
21  19
68  55
10  16
33  54
3   1
5   9
```

I am trying to read in input.txt file that looks like input above but the problem is that the program only reads in the last line from the text file.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * 
 */
public class ReadIn {


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    //List<Integer> value = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    //List<Integer> weight = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    FileReader readFile = new FileReader ("C:\\Users\\owner\\IdeaProjects\\knapsack\\src\\input");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(readFile);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(br);
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    //List<Items> items = new ArrayList<Items>();


    Items[] items= new Items[23];//this only creates references that are set to their default value null which throws a null exception
    for(int i =0 ; i <items.length; i++) {//fixes null exception

        items[i] = new Items();//fully creates the objects

        while (input.hasNext()) {//read in file input to object data
            items[i].setValue(input.nextInt());
            items[i].setWeight(input.nextInt());
            items[i].setId(i);
        }
    }
    input.close();
    input.reset();
    System.out.println("What is the max capacity for the knapsack? ");
    Integer maxCapacity = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println(maxCapacity);
    int[] maxWeight = new int[maxCapacity];//creates int array so we can use the index as the maxWeight as the number of fields
    printArray(items);

}
    public static void printArray(Items[] x) {

        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i] = new Items();
            System.out.println(x[i].getValue() + " " + x[i].getWeight() + " " + x[i].getId() + " ");
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks for the help I am stuck!!
I have also attached the Items class that i am trying to use

```
    public class Items {
        private Integer value ;
        private Integer weight;
        private Integer Id;

        public Items(){
            this.value = 0;
            this.weight = 0;
            this.Id =0;
        }

        public Items(Integer v, Integer w, Integer ID){
            this.value = v;
            this.weight = w;
            this.Id = ID;
        }


        public Integer getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(Integer value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public Integer getWeight() {
            return weight;
        }

        public void setWeight(Integer weight) {
            this.weight = weight;
        }

        public Integer getId() {
            return Id;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {//sets id
            Id = id;
        }
    }
```

This is the end of the code

Comment: Where did you set `j` ? you forgot to increment it at the end of the while loop...

Comment: i just edited it thank you

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will be useful:

**UPDATE:**

You should declare and initialize the **`j`** variable and within the **`while`** loop the variable **`j`** increases by 1 in each loop:

```
int j=0; // ----> initialize j variable
while (input.hasNext()) {
    items[j].setValue(input.nextInt());
    items[j].setWeight(input.nextInt());
    items[j].setId(j);
    j++; // ----> increment 1 y each loop
}
```

In the `printArray (Items[] x)` method inside the for loop you should not define this:

```
x[i] = new Items();
```

because in each iteration create a new object and when print it will be **`0 0 0`**

---

**Here the example:**

```
public class MyTree {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        FileReader readFile = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\owner\\IdeaProjects\\knapsack\\src\\input");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(readFile);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(br);
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        Items[] items = new Items[23];//this only creates references that are set to their default value null which throws a null exception
        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {//fixes null exception
            items[i] = new Items();//fully creates the objects
        }

        int j=0; // ----> initialize j variable
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            items[j].setValue(input.nextInt());
            items[j].setWeight(input.nextInt());
            items[j].setId(j);
            j++; // ----> increment 1 y each loop
        }

        input.close();
        input.reset();
        System.out.println("What is the max capacity for the knapsack? ");
        Integer maxCapacity = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println(maxCapacity);
        int[] maxWeight = new int[maxCapacity];//creates int array so we can use the index as the maxWeight as the number of fields
        printArray(items);

    }

    public static void printArray(Items[] x) {

        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            //x[i] = new Items();  //It shouldn't be here, because in each iteration create a new object
            System.out.println(x[i].getValue() + " " + x[i].getWeight() + " " + x[i].getId() + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad you want to help. Code only answers are very rarely useful. Better give some explanation of how the code might help the asker and answer the question.

Comment: In the code I wrote a comment with the changes. Thanks for your feedback I'm going to update the answer

Comment: Thanks for your help removing the x[i] = new Items(); did the trick

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the for-loop, use a list instead of an array and read each item and add it to the list:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    FileReader readFile = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\owner\\IdeaProjects\\knapsack\\src\\input");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(readFile);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(br);

    List<Item> items= new LinkedList<>();
    int i = 0;
    while (input.hasNext()) {
        Item item = new Item();
        item.setValue(input.nextInt());
        item.setWeight(input.nextInt());
        item.setId(i);
        items.add(item);
        i++;
    }
    input.close();
    input.reset();
    //...
}
```

Two more comments:

1. class `Items` should be called `Item`
2. you should consider adding a `toString()` method to class `Item` this way it'll be easy to print

Comment: Thanks I will make this my fall back plan if I can't finish my code thanks again.

Comment: @dster05 using the array and pre-initializing and filling it with objects is a bad idea for a few reasons: 1. you have to know in advance the number of lines in the file. 2. if you got it wrong you miss some lines or worse, create more objects that will remain "unused" but your program has no way to know it - this might cause other issues down the road. 3. Array has fixed size - you can't add/remove objects to it without needing to create a new array and copying all the existing objects to it.

Comment: Further, arrays don't mix with generics very well. You can read some more about why you should prefer lists over arrays in Java here: https://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA119&lpg=PA119&dq=bloch+prefer+lists+to+arrays&source=bl&ots=yZLgIet4T4&sig=K7qnkhqj5CleiehZVQlZVsxYrO4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0hKeLgYLTAhUO4mMKHZRDDJkQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=bloch%20prefer%20lists%20to%20arrays&f=false

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in the *for-loop* below. You do a while-loop without actually changing the destination, so everything gets overwritten and only the last input prevails. There are two possibilities to fix this. Both of those only work optimally under the assumption that the input file is correctly formatted. Other changes would need to be adjusted to make it fail proof.

```
//---------Option 1: Remove the While-loop----
for(int i =0 ; i <items.length; i++) {//fixes null exception

    items[i] = new Items();//fully creates the objects
    items[i].setValue(input.nextInt());
    items[i].setWeight(input.nextInt());
    items[i].setId(i);
}


//---------Option 2: Let the for-loop finish before the while-loop ------
for(int i =0 ; i <items.length; i++) { //fixes null exception
    items[i] = new Items(); //fully creates the objects
}

int k=0; //Need a variable for count
while (input.hasNext()) {
    items[k].setValue(input.nextInt());
    items[k].setWeight(input.nextInt());
    items[k].setId(k);
    k++;
}
```